# Storing relationships between tables at the application layer in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, data-modeling

Would it be out-of-the-question in terms of performance to store a simple map of particular foreign key relationships in-memory in a Node application?

The reason for this is to avoid unnecessary queries to a MySQL database for information on the relationships between tables. Why don't I already know the specific relationship within the application? Because tables can be created at runtime (does this sit well as a concept?) and therefore so can their relationships.

I was thinking of using a module like [node-dirty](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty) for persistance when restarting the app.

Comment: Is your database structure not already set? It is a bit strange to have to query your database to figure out what its structure is.

Comment: @Seventoes The idea is that models (in the traditional ORM sense) can be set at runtime. So an administrator/editor (without the nouse to go and write code) can create a new ORM model through an HTTP interface, and start instantiating that model in the database thereafter. I'm surprised at the lack of response to this question as I was expecting either adverse objection by data-modelling enthusiasts or enthusiastic debate at the very least.